# Cast a pair containing void pointers to a pair of pointers of other type

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, casting, void-pointers

### Discussion

I know that the proper way to cast a `void` pointer to a pointer of other type is to use `static_cast`. (e.g.,

```
void *vptr;
...
foo* fptr = static_cast<foo*>(vptr);
```

)

What I have though, is a pair of `void` pointers (i.e., `std::pair<void*, void*>`), which I want to cast it to a pair of pointers of other type (e.g., `std::pair<foo*, bar*>`).

The most naive way I can think of to achieve this is the following:

```
std::pair<void*, void*> vpr;
...
std::pair<foo*, bar*> fbpr = std::make_pair(static_cast<foo*>(vpr.first), static_cast<bar*>(vpr.second));
```

Or since C++11:

```
std::pair<void*, void*> vpr;
...
auto fbpr = std::make_pair(static_cast<foo*>(vpr.first), static_cast<bar*>(vpr.second));
```

### Question

Is there a neater, more elegant or efficient way to do this casting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could factor it out into a `pair_cast` function:

```
template <typename D1, typename D2, typename S1, typename S2>
std::pair<D1,D2> pair_cast (const std::pair<S1,S2>& p) {
    return { static_cast<D1>(p.first), static_cast<D2>(p.second) };   
}
```

Then call like this:

```
pair_cast<foo*, bar*>(vpr);
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eebcc91482344bd5)

Comment: I'd suggest using `static_pair_cast<...>(...)` and `dynamic_pair_cast<...>(...)`. They'd be along the same lines, though.

Comment: @DietmarKühl yeah, that would be more in line with `std::static_pointer_cast` and friends. This is left as an exercise to the reader :p

Comment: @TartanLlama when's the deadline? :P. Thanx a lot!